# Printing text after searching for a string

Tags: python, regex

I am following a tutorial to identify and print the words in between a particular string;

`f` is the string `Mango grapes Lemon Ginger Pineapple`

```
def findFruit(f):
    global fruit
    found = [re.search(r'(.*?) (Lemon) (.*?)$', word) for word in f]
        for i in found:
            if i is not None:
                fruit = i.group(1)
                fruit = i.group(3)
```

`grapes` and `Ginger` will be outputted when i print `fruit`. However what i want the output is to look like `"grapes" # "Ginger"` (note the `""` and `#` sign).

Comment: I'm confused. Why not `print '"{}" # "{}"'.format(i.group(1), i.group(3))`

Comment: or `"{0}" # "{2}"'.format(*i.groups())`

Comment: @Haidro I'm confused. Why comment instead of answer? :)

Comment: @RomanPekar Added an answer. I was a bit confused by the amount of upvotes. I thought there was something I was missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting) here with the use of the [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function:

```
def findFruit(f):
    found = re.search(r'.*? (.*?) Lemon (.*?) .*?$', f)
    if found is not None:
       print '"{}" # "{}"'.format(found.group(1), found.group(2))
```

Or, a lovely solution Kimvais posted in the comments:

```
print '"{0}" # "{1}"'.format(*found.groups())
```

---

I've done some edits. Firstly, a for-loop isn't needed here (nor is a list comprehension. You're iterating through each letter of the string, instead of each word. Even then you don't want to iterate through each word.

I also changed your regular expression (Do note that I'm not that great in regex, so there probably is a better solution).

Comment: That's not the only problem. When i pass the string `Mango grapes Lemon Ginger Pineapple` (which is passed as a parameter `f`), it doesn't give any output.